# Match exact word is available or not in string in php

Tags: php

I have below string i want to exact word is available or not in php
Example

```
$String = 'http://www.testurl.com/article/test.php';
$word = '/article/';
```

Now i want to check `'/article/'` is available or not in string, if the word is not contain start start and end slash then it should be return false.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you're really just searching on a literal string match, you may use `strpos` here:

```php
$input = 'http://www.testurl.com/article/test.php';
$word = '/article/';
if (strpos($input, $word) !== false) {
    echo "Word Found!";
}
else {
    echo "Word Not Found!";
}
```

You may also use `preg_match` here:

```php
$input = 'http://www.testurl.com/article/test.php';
if (preg_match("$/article/$", $input)) {
    echo "YES";  // prints YES
}
```

Note here that we are using `$` as the delimiter character in the pattern being passed to `preg_match`.  More typically, we see `/` being used, but you are trying to actually match literal forward slashes, we use something else.

Comment: I tried above code, but it gives me true also, when my $word = 'article'. It should give false if the word not start OR end with "/"

Comment: Then search on `/article/` only.  I don't see the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Notwithstanding the fine answer from Tim, you may also be interested in a (admittedly less elegant) solution with logic to find a word match in a string.

We use the fact that the string datatype allows array-like(`[]`) access to characters in a string. I.e. we can iterate through the string to find a word match using this technique.

```
<?php

$match = findWord($word, $string);

function findWord(string $word, string $string)
{
    $len = strlen($string);
    $lenWord = strlen($word);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
        $match = '';
        if ($string[$i] === $word[0]) {
            $match .= $word[0];// found a match for first char of $word
            for ($j = 1; $j < $lenWord; $j++) { // see if we can match whole word char by char
                if (isset($string[$i+$j]) && $word[$j] === $string[$i + $j]) {
                    $match .= $string[$i + $j];
                } else break;
            }
            if ($match === $word) return $match; // we have a full match
        }
    }
    return false; // no match found
}
```

You can play with the function in this [demo](https://3v4l.org/nufeT)